# Ajax data only works for get

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax in JavaScript to send a request to my Asp.Net Web Api like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/Api/User/Test",
    data: {
        "Id": "1",
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});
```

**Web Api:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test(string Id, string FirstName, string LastName)
{
...
}
```

So it doesn't work whenever I use `POST` as my `Ajax` type. But when I change it to `GET` as well as the Web Api function it works fine. What I mean with it doesn't work is that I can see that the request doesn't transfer the data (Id, FirstName, LastName). Why is that? What can I do that the `POST` method works as well. I would rather avoid using `JObject` or a `Model`.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use multiple parameters with post in API. You can use only that

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody]string Id)
{
...
}
```

Or you can use post with an object. İf you have to multiple parameters you have to use get etc.

Comment: Why can't I use multiple parameters with post?